# Angular BehaviouralSubjects

Tags: angular, asynchronous

The problem is Splice on array taken from subscription of behavioural subject as type array, seems to manipulate directily on the subjects value

i isolated the problem down to a very small but precise problem.

```
      this.aktiver.aktiver$.subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
      const x = res;

      x.forEach((ele , i) => {
        x.splice(i);
      })
    })
...

the output of the log gives me an array of 2 elements, but, when i open it, its empty, and says "value below was edited just now"
so the splice seems to have edited the original value of the behavioural subject that is aktiver$

i thought this couldnt happen, any ideas what is going wrong in my example?
```

Comment: use `.slice` instead of `splice`. ```x = x.slice(i)```.. also ```x = [...res]```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here

```
      const x = res;
```

you aren't copying the array, you're creating another reference for the same object. At this point, `x` and `res` point at the same thing, and any mutation made on `x` *is* a mutation made on `res`.

To (shallow) copy, do

```
      const x = [...res];
```

instead.

Comment: hm.. yeah lol that worked... even const x = [res] alone worked..

anyway, i still really dont get the "why" , i thought that the only way an async could be manipulated was through next? , or that might just be the way, to call other subscribers?

Comment: when you use `x = res`, you're altering the original array. In this case, you are creating another array and spreading the content of `res` in it and then assigning 'x' to this new array. You should always follow this practice, Therefore, you might wanna change your `splice` with `x = x.slice(i)`. Read up on `mutation`

Answer (score 0):

update:

```
    this.aktiver.aktiver$.subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
      const x = new Array<KontoOpdeler>();
      res.forEach(ele => {
        x.push(ele);
      })


      x.forEach((ele , i) => {
        x.splice(i);
      });
    });
```

Is working, but it's an ugly solution, and not identifying my problem